# How do you divide json array into two arr? and empty [] by firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of json by firestore
firesotre join well

my code

```
   let query_chart =db.collection('collection').doc('date')

   let chart_data_json =[];
   query_chart.get().then(doc=>{

    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
      } else {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data().time);
        const time = doc.data().time;
        Object.keys(time).map(hour=>{
            const count = time[hour];
            chart_data_json.push({
                hour : hour,
                count: count
            })
        })
        console.log(chart_data_json);

      }
})

let hour=[];
let time=[];
```

and

my console log this

```
[]
0: {hour: "12", count: 0}
1: {hour: "13", count: 0}
2: {hour: "14", count: 0}
3: {hour: "15", count: 1}
4: {hour: "16", count: 0}
5: {hour: "17", count: 0}
6: {hour: "18", count: 0}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I used the code to access that array.

```
console.log("array",chart_data_json);
```

but 
The console printed

```
"array"undefined
```

what empty [] in object?

And how do you approach it and divide it into two array 'hour' and 'time'?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit what do you mean by " what empty [] in object? " . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`[].map()` returns a new Array, so you need to get it like:

```
    // get the new list here
    chart_data_json = Object.keys(time).map(hour=>{
        const count = time[hour];
        return { // <--------------return from here
            hour : hour,
            count: count
        }
    })
```

Comment: What I want to know is why does log output to [{...},{...}] instead of format? This is the method of accessing an array that is output by [].

Answer (score 0):

Here you stated that you have an array of json. Assuming that "time" has the array, running Object.keys(time) will give you an array of Indexes. [0,1,2,3].
You need to iterate on the Array (time) and then you can run the map in the loop.